# How to create button with dynamic width in Skia React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, skia

I want to create a button using Skia library in React Native. The width of button should expand acconding to text or content in it.

Thanks.

Comment: what is skia? is it a library?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox
https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation.html
these two togheter will get you very far.

Answer (score 0):

If you're aiming for creating a button with the Skia library in React Native you probably have some drawing magic on your mind. If you really need this for a button then I would advice to check out the excellent tutorials of William Candillon: https://www.youtube.com/c/wcandillon/videos

In the example shown here at Shopify you can already find some tips towards building the button you would need: https://shopify.engineering/react-native-skia-shopify

Comment: Thank you so much, there are not enough documentation I could find on skia.